# Clicking on a input makes the whole page blurry

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a login form, But when I click on one of my inputs it make the whole page a little blurry as you can see in the images and I don't know why because also there is no pages or articles related to this.

**After clicking** (A little blurred):

[image: after]

**Before Clicking** (Clear):

[image: before]

**My css code related to inputs**:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #010203;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* Firefox */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #010203;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #010203;
}

input.Submit {
  width: 13.18em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #50e0ff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input.Submit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.text {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 12.97em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input.password {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 12.97em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.password-div-wouidhawd {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.from_Input {
  outline: none;
  color: #010203;
  background-color: #f2f6fb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.from_Input:active {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div id="row" class="row box-shadow-main-content-box-dyigawdaowd">
  <div class="column2">
    <i
      title="بازگشت به صفحه اصلی"
      class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2xl back"
      onClick="window.location.href='./index.php'"
      aria-hidden="true"
      id="back"
    ></i>
    <h2 class="heading">مدرسه زنده یاد الویری</h2>
    <p class="sub-heading">
      برای استفاده از داشبورد، به حساب خود وارد شوید
    </p>
    <form method="post">
      <div class="inputs-div">
        <input
          dir="ltr"
          class="align from_Input text"
          type="text"
          autocomplete="new-username"
          name="username"
          placeholder="نام کاربری"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div class="inputs-div password-div-wouidhawd">
        <input
          dir="ltr"
          id="toggle_password"
          autocomplete="new-password"
          class="align from_Input password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="رمز"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div class="inputs-div remember-sec">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          class="checkbox"
          value="remember"
          id="rememberme"
          name="rememberme"
        />
        <label for="rememberme" class="forget-text">مرا بخاطر بسپار</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs-div">
        <input
          style="border: 0px; border-radius: 20px; color: #fff"
          id="submit"
          class="Submit"
          value="ورود"
          type="submit"
        />
    </div>
    </form>
    <?php if (isset($error)):
      echo $error;
    endif; ?>
    <div class="others-sec">
      <div class="forgot-sec">
        <a href="#" class="forgot-btn" id="forgot" onClick="swal()"
          >رمز عبور خود را فراموش کرده اید؟</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because of the popup, have you tried it in other browsers?

Comment: No I didn't, I just tried it on chrome